# How to center this card?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am facing a problem with cards that I had made with `swiperjs`. I am trying to center the card in the mobile screen but I couldn't. Please help me to fix it.

[image: Screen of problem]

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  centerSlide: 'true',
  fade: 'true',
  grabCursor: 'true',
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you share project link if this is on live server ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
  slidesPerView: 1, // Set the number of visible slides to 1
  loop: true,
  centerSlides: true, // Use 'centerSlides' instead of 'centerSlide'
  fadeEffect: true, // Use 'fadeEffect' instead of 'fade'
  grabCursor: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
```